# Use variable outside of promise block in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular6

How can I get a variable outside of a promise block in a component in Angular 6?

For example

```js
    items:string[]=[];

    ngOnInit{

    const url='SOME URL';
    const promise = this.apiService.post(url);

        //Response
        promise.then(response => {
      this.items.push('abc');
      this.items.push('def');
        });

    this.items.forEach(item=>{
     alert(item);
    });

      }
```

I expect that the application alerts the contents of the items array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
this.items.forEach(item=>{
     alert(item);
    });
```

the items array is empty.

You need put this code inside

```
  promise.then(response => {
          this.items.push('abc');
          this.items.push('def');
         this.items.forEach(item=>{
            alert(item);
           });
     });
```

Or you can use Observables to know when the promise ends and execute the foreach, you need to do something like this:

```
private subjectItems = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit{

    this.subjectItems.asObservable().subscribe(o => {
        this.items.forEach(item=>{
         alert(item);
        });
      });

    const url='SOME URL';
    const promise = this.apiService.post(url);

        //Response
        promise.then(response => {
           this.items.push('abc');
           this.items.push('def');

           this.subjectItems.next(this.items)
        });
      }
```

Comment: The problem is that I want that the application alerts the items outside the promise block because I want to use the items variable outside the promise block

Comment: You must have some way of knowing that the promise has resolved. The reason for putting the alert inside the block after `.then` is that you know your  promise has resolved at that point. Otherwise, you may execute the `thisitems.forEach(item => alert(item))` at a time when the promise hasn't resolved yet, hence showing nothing as the list is empty. If you are trying to use `this.items` in your template you should be fine as it would update when the value changes anyways.

Comment: @freelancer86 i edit my answer to add other approach, with observables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an async issue, I mean your alert is being shown before you get data from the service, so an option would be to work with `Observables` and `subscribe`. It should wait until getting data before using it.

Also you could try using `async/await` following this [medium article](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)